# Clarification regarding Axler's proof that if $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly independent and $\in V$, and $w_1,\cdots,w_m$ span $V$, then $n \leq m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to learn some of the basics of linear algebra and, for my own purposes, wanted to prove the following claim:

> **Theorem**: In a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, if the vectors $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ are linearly independent, then any set $S=\{w_1,\cdots, w_m\}$ where $\text{span}(S)=V$ must satisfy $n \leq m$.

I saw that a common approach used to prove this theorem is found in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. The book provides an 'algorithm' that leverages the assumptions such that we can throw out $w_i$ vectors from $S$ and replace them, one by one, with the $v_j$ vectors. From what I have seen, the resulting set of vectors is described as:

$$\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n,w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_k\}$$ where $0\leq k \lt m$. In the event $k=0$, that simply means no $w_i$ remain in the list.

My confusion with this depiction is that it seems like we are implicitly assuming that $n \leq m$ *to begin with* (which is clearly begging the question).

Is it more **formally appropriate** to actually structure this proof as a **proof by contradiction**, where we start by assuming $n > m$ and then proceed to implement the algorithm, letting our final set look like:

$$\{v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_k\}$$ where $k \lt n$. At this point, you would observe that $\text{span}\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}=V$ clearly contradicts the fact that the vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly independent.

Here is a picture of the algorithm:

[image: Picture]

Comment: That proof is standard and fine. The author is not "implicitly assuming that $n≤m$
 to begin with". He is proving it in the  end. He explains (with distinct notations from yours) starting from the list $w_1,\dots,w_m,$ how to insert one by one all your $v_j$'s by removing one of your $w_i$'s each time, so that the list remains of length $m$ and finally contains $v_1,\dots,v_n,$ which clearly implies $n\le m.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I am having difficulties understanding why you can remove $n$ instances of unique $w_i$'s from a list that contains $m$ such unique instances without first assuming that $n \leq m$. Where did I go wrong in my thought process?

Comment: The fact that the algorithm allows this repeated replacement as long as there remains some $v_j$'s to put in (without first assuming that inequality) is detailed in "Step $j$".

Comment: For reference, this is called the Steinitz exchange algorithm.